# Where could i find a windows 10 ISO?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image

I'm trying to get a Windows 10 ISO for a virtual campaign soon, but I am unable to find a website that has the Windows 10 ISO. I mostly use WinWorld, but it lacks an ISO, and there's no way of newer versions at the download site.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

This will download a tool, which may burn the installer DVD or prepare a USB drive. You may even install it without a key.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate...

Comment: No problem. The question is a duplicate too.